# SwiftUI: how to resize the UIViewRepresentable output?

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable, phlivephoto

I try to build a basic Live Photo app on SwiftUI and struggle with display of the selected photo. To do so I tried to make UIViewRepresentable for PHLivePhotoView:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct LivePhotoView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var livephoto: PHLivePhoto

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PHLivePhotoView {
        return PHLivePhotoView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ lpView: PHLivePhotoView, context: Context) {
        lpView.livePhoto = livephoto
    }
}
```

In my Main view I call it like that:

```swift
if pickerResult.count > 0 {
    LivePhotoView(livephoto: $pickerResult[0])
}
```

It works fine up to the moment when I try to restrict the view size. I want to put the preview into a square box with something like that

```swift
LivePhotoView(livephoto: $pickerResult[0])
    .scaledToFit()
    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.width, alignment: .center)
```

but scaledToFit() doesn't seem to work, all I have is a cropped image. Expected behaviour is to have an image with preserved aspect ratio and an empty space on a shorter side. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it on original view and in SwiftUI only limit a frame, like

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PHLivePhotoView {
    let photoView = PHLivePhotoView()
    photoView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return photoView
}
```

and (or even w/o) `frame` modifier

```
LivePhotoView(livephoto: $pickerResult[0])
    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.width, alignment: .center)
```

Comment: I love stack overflow and almost love you now for answering my second questions today! I spent good two hours fighting and then you bring a working solution in three minutes. 
Just a small remark, it's ```.scaleAspectFit```, but it works!